# Strange Network setup, 2 Different routers - same MAC (which is not the router mac)

Tags: networking, setup

I got some course exercise - I need to figure out how the network works and what is the missing component.

The network setup is -

1. A Windows PC (the client)
2. Two Routers - 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.2.1
3. Some missing component that I need to figure out.

So, what I know - There are *2* Different Routers, in 2 different subnets, the Client computer can connect to each of them just by changing the IP configuration (setting a static IP). The Strange part starts now, **both routers have the same MAC address AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF in the client's ARP,
and it's not the MAC of any of them - I believe its the mac of the missing component** :

```
arp -a (on client) 
192.168.1.1 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
192.168.2.1 AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

So the missing component has no IP, but the MAC address of the gateway in the computer's arp cache is the mac address of the component.

I had some ideas about that -

1. HUB - it's just electricity, so nothing should be changed
2. Switch - No need to change the mac address
3. Router - why the IP of the configured gateway is the real gateway ?

SO, I don't think it's a regular Switch, hub or a Router.

Do anyone ever seen such setup? any ideas what can it be ? I am really confused ... looks like if some component is doing an ARP spoof XD.

Network Diagram

[image: IMG:]

Comment: See if my edit above was correct. For your question, I would guess an unmanaged switch connected to both routers.

Comment: 1) How do you know it's _two_ routers, and not just one router with two IP addresses? 2) What is the actual MAC address, or at least the first half of it?

Comment: @harrymc, it was incorrect, changed back, both routers have same mac address in the client's arp cache, and the mac is really not their mac

Comment: I know that these are 2 routers, it's just given information, while their vendors are TPLink and DLink, and the mac in the client's arp cache is a DLink mac, but even the first 3 bytes of the mac are different, I am sure that it's additional device

Comment: edit: Added a network diagram, maybe will be more clear now

Comment: I would still guess an unmanaged switch that has MAC but no IP.

Comment: @harrymc in what scenario would an unmanaged switch respond to ARP requests if it doesn’t have an IP and likely doesn’t understand Layer 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unknown component cannot be an Layer-2 managed switch, or it would itself be
a host on the network with its own MAC and IP addresses.
To be without an IP address of its own, it must be an unmanaged L2 switch.
As usually an unmanaged switch does not have a MAC address, it must be a
special-purpose switch.

Switches technically work at Layer-2, handling Layer-2 addresses in L2 frames
for determining to which port to forward.

Typically, a switch will not have its own MAC address, and hence will not need
to respond to ARP requests. ARP frames are just another L2 frame to a regular switch,
which get forwarded based on their destination MAC addresses
(usually broadcast for ARP requests and unicast for ARP responses).

However, some switches are designed to be a bit smarter, not just to interpret
Layer-2 signaling/control protocols, but also to do some basic Layer-3 functionality.

Specifics will vary depending on features supported. This includes
DHCP relay, IGMP snooping, MCAST optimizations, L4-ACL/QoS, Proxy-ARP, etc.
For some of these, the switch may respond to an ARP request.

These switches add special handling to the packet processing pipeline so as to
pick out ARP frames for further inspection, so these frames are processed differently
than other L2 frames. The embedded IP address inside the ARP request payload
will be looked at as needed for the specific function implemented by the switch.

For this special handling, the switch isn't limited to just L2 headers,
and is allowed to look deeper into the ARP frames and have its own MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure if there is enough information here, but this sounds like the work of Proxy ARP.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP

Whether the Proxy ARP behavior is present to support some other technology, like a Layer 2 WAN connection or VPN server, is debatable. It’s used in many scenarios where devices that are on different physical networks are required to participate on the same logical IP subnet.

Further reading: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1027